# split the text in td and display in newline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text, split

Example ==> [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/G8tiFBqnS7GwhwqBYxYm?p=preview)

What I did: From the above, I am passing the below text in the table -- td(logs).

What Needed: Need to split the text ends with **\"**. And display on a new line.

> "\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi,
>   necessitatibus.\", \" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipisicing elit. Animi, necessitatibus.]  \",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, necessitatibus.\", \"Lorem
>   ipsum dolor sit amet.  \","

**scripts.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('splitText', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "text";
  $scope.log = "\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, necessitatibus.\", \" Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, necessitatibus.]  \",\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, necessitatibus.\", \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  \",";
  $scope.logs = $scope.log.replace(/,/g, '\n');
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="splitText" class="container">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <p class="">{{text}}</p>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Logs</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Log</td>
        <td>{{logs}}</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I realized, your regex is actually fine, what is the problem?

Comment: @Roljhon No luck. I want to split the <td> text which ends with \". And need to display the split text in new line(one by one)

Comment: It's actually working, in plunker if you adjust the window for the output, it will show you like it didn't. Try `console.log()`

Comment: Yeah, i can able to see the text in a new line in the console. But it comes to the table data it's shrinking.

Comment: You should better update your OP, it's quite confusing of what you really want. Set a fix width for your 3rd td which will prevent the text from shrinking, it's actually a normal behavior of table element.